# Download file from AZURE BLOB CONTAINER using SAS URI in PYTHON

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

**I have Azure container where i keep some files.
I need to access them using python code
I did same thing in JAVA but i am unable to replicate it in Python**

//This is java code for same.

```
CloudBlobContainer Con = new CloudBlobContainer("Some SAS URI");

CloudBlockBlob blob1 = Con.getBlockBlobReference(fileName);

blob1.downloadToFile(filePath+fileName+userName);
```

Comment: What kind of SAS URI do you have? Is it for the blob container or blob? Please edit your question and include the SAS URI (you can obfuscate the account name and sig portion of the SAS URI).

Answer (score 3):

There is no equivalent method in python, you can take a look at the [Container class of python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.models.container?view=azure-python)

You should always use `BlockBlobService`  with sas token(if you have a sas uri, you can get sas token from it) or account key, like below if you use sas token:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

blobservice = BlockBlobService("storage_account",sas_token="?sv=2018-03-28&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2019-04-24T10:01:58Z&st=2019-04-23T02:01:58Z&spr=https&sig=xxxxxxxxx")
blobservice.get_blob_to_path("container_name","blob_name","local_file_path")
```

Comment: Yes it works fine thanks I didn't knew that BlockBlobService method has sas_token parameter also.

Comment: @Amitvishnoi, could you please help mark it as an answer. here is the [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) of how to mark if you don't know, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using newer version that does not have `BlockBlobService`, you can use `BlobClient`:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient

blob_client = BlobClient.from_blob_url(sas_url)
with open(file=blob_client.blob_name, mode="wb") as blob_file:
    download_stream = blob_client.download_blob()
    blob_file.write(download_stream.readall())
```