# Python: Upload a package to Azure using SAS URI

Tags: python-3.x, rest, azure-blob-storage

I am using the Microsoft's Hardware dashboard API to automate the submission of my (.CAB) package for signing. I have followed the steps in this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/dashboard/create-a-new-submission-for-a-product

The response of new submission contains the SAS(Shared Access Signature) URI 
like this: (changed the sig and accnt_name for security)

'''https://accnt_name.blob.core.windows.net/scsjc/cexxxxxxxxxx?sv=2017-04-17&sr=b&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&se=2019-07-10T18:15:58Z&sp=rwl&rscd=attachment%3B filename%3Dinitial_xxxxxxxx.cab'''

**I need to use this SAS URI to upload by package to azure blob storage.**
The examples in documentation shows C# or .NET as follows:

```
string sasUrl = 
"https://productingestionbin1.blob.core.windows.net/ingestion/26920f66- 
 b592-4439-9a9d-fb0f014902ec?sv=2014-02-
 14&sr=b&sig=usAN0kNFNnYE2tGQBI%2BARQWejX1Guiz7hdFtRhyK%2Bog%3D&se=2016- 
 06-17T20:45:51Z&sp=rwl";
 Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob blockBob =
 new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob(new 
 System.Uri(sasUrl));
 await blockBob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);
```

I want to use the SAS URI obtained from submission resource JSON Response to upload the package.

This link [Download file from AZURE BLOB CONTAINER using SAS URI in PYTHON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55794030/download-file-from-azure-blob-container-using-sas-uri-in-python) suggests that there is no equivalent method in python and BlockBlobService can be used.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

 blobservice = BlockBlobService("storage_account",sas_token="?sv=2018-03- 
 28&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2019-04-24T10:01:58Z&st=2019-04- 
 23T02:01:58Z&spr=https&sig=xxxxxxxxx")

 blobservice.create_blob_from_path(container_name, local_file_name, 
 full_path_to_file)
```

However I am not sure of what is storage_account name and container name from the SAS URI obtained from submission resource.

Also I have created a separate azure storage account and added a new container, blob in it. I have tried passing the new container and storage account name with SAS access token from SAS URI (obtained from submission JSON response micorsoft hardware api)  but always get below **ERROR**

'''
AzureHttpError: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. ErrorCode: AuthenticationFailed
`AuthenticationFailed`Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:5463b7d2-901e-0068-6994-36782e000000
Time:2019-07-09T20:23:04.5760736ZSignature did not match. String to sign used was rwl

2019-07-10T18:15:58Z
/blob/evcertautomation/ev2/initial_1152921504628106590.cab

2017-04-17

attachment; filename=initial_1152921504628106563.cab

'''
Thanks in advance

Comment: From the SAS URI you provide: 'https://accnt_name.blob.core.windows.net/scsjc/cexxxxxxxxxx?sv=2017-04xxxx, the storage_account name is accnt_name, the container name is scsjc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a blob SAS URI as you post below, you can easily upload a file to the blob in Python with `requests`.

`https://accnt_name.blob.core.windows.net/scsjc/cexxxxxxxxxx?sv=2017-04-17&sr=b&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&se=2019-07-10T18:15:58Z&sp=rwl&rscd=attachment%3B filename%3Dinitial_xxxxxxxx.cab`

First, you must have to inspect the values of parameters `se` and `sp`. The `se` parameter means the expire time of the blob SAS URI, and the `sp` parameter means the operation permisson of the blob SAS URL like `w` for Blob Write Permission

So for your blob SAS URL above, you have the blob write permission to upload a file to this blob before the time `2019-07-10T18:15:58Z`.

Here is my sample code for uploading via a blob sas uri.

```
import requests

blob_sas_uri = '<your blob sas uri which must includes `sp=w` and do the write operation before `se`>'

local_file_name = '<your local file name>'

headers = {
    'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob'
}

data = open(local_file_name).read()

r = requests.put(blob_sas_uri, headers=headers, data=data)
print(r.status_code)
```

If you see the result is `201`, it works fine and succeed for uploading.

As reference, there is a similar offical sample [`Example: Upload a Blob using a Container’s Shared Access Signature`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/service-sas-examples#example-upload-a-blob-using-a-containers-shared-access-signature) which using a wide container permission.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have used the following code using requests and it works!!!         f = open(full_path_to_file, 'rb')
uploadResponse = requests.put(fileUploadUrl.replace("+", "%3B"), f, headers={"x-ms-blob-type": "BlockBlob"})
print(uploadResponse.status_code)

Answer (score 0):

As per the SAS URI you provided: '''https://accnt_name.blob.core.windows.net/scsjc/cexxxxxxxxxx?sv=2017-04-17&sr=b&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&se=2019-07-10T18:15:58Z&sp=rwl&rscd=attachment%3B filename%3Dinitial_xxxxxxxx.cab'''

The account name should be **accnt_name**, the container should be **scsjc**.

So your code should look like below:

```
 from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

storage_account ="accnt_name"
token="?sv=2018-03- 
 28&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2019-04-24T10:01:58Z&st=2019-04- 
 23T02:01:58Z&spr=https&sig=xxxxxxxxx"

container="scsjc"

 blobservice = BlockBlobService(storage_account,sas_token=token)

 blobservice.create_blob_from_path(container, local_file_name, 
 full_path_to_file)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Ivan. The storage_account and token seems to work! However, the problem is with SAS token.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for the token to start from ?sv and not cexxxxxxxxxx? I have tried to use the token as you suggested but it says se and sp are mandatory. I have used below 3 sas token: **No 1**: ?sv=2018-03- 
 28&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2019-04-24T10:01:58Z&st=2019-04- 
 23T02:01:58Z&spr=https&sig=xxxxxxxxx''  **No 2**: ?sv=2018-03- 
 28&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2019-04-24T10:01:58Z&st=2019-04- 
 23T02:01:58Z&spr=https&sig=xxxxxxxxx&se=2019-07-10T18:15:58Z&sp=rwl

Comment: **No 3**: cexxxxxxxxxx?sv=2017-04-17&sr=b&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&se=2019-07-10T18:15:58Z&sp=rwl&rscd=attachment%3B filename%3Dinitial_xxxxxxxx.cab However all are giving me error: **Signature did not match. String to sign used was rwl**  I really appreciate the help on this!

Comment: it should start with "?sv", and also note that the se means sas token expires time, you cannot change it except that you generate sas token manually.