# python read from azure storage account

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake

Having hard time in reading a .csv file that is stored in a storage container. I have these details for the container to access: "Blob SAS token" and "Blob SAS URL"

I have been referring to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/458240/how-to-read-a-file-from-azure-blob-container-using.html), [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/data-science-process/explore-data-blob) but they don't use the "Blob SAS token" or "Blob SAS URL"

Can someone help with a python code that enables to read the data as a data frame?

Comment: Hi, If my reply helped you kindly mark it as the answer so the community is aware that this question is closed.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python), it shows how to use a sas url to create a BlobClient. Once you have this, you can follow the instruction in the [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/data-science-process/explore-data-blob) you shared.

Your final code will look like this.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

sas_url = "<your_blob_sas url>"
blob_client = BlobClient.from_blob_url(sas_url)
blob_data = blob_client.download_blob()
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(blob_data.content_as_text()))
print(df)
```

To upload a dataframe to a container, you can try the following code

```
from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient

sas_url = "https://<acct_name>.blob.core.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
container = ContainerClient.from_container_url(sas_url)

output = io.StringIO()
head = ["col1" , "col2" , "col3"]
l = [[1 , 2 , 3],[4,5,6] , [8 , 7 , 9]]
df = pd.DataFrame (l , columns = head)
print(df)
output = df.to_csv (index_label="idx", encoding = "utf-8")

blob_client = container_client.upload_blob(name="myblob", data=output)
```

Comment: The above was helpful in reading the data. Can you also assist me with uploading a dataframe to a container with blob sas url (i do have all permissions)

Comment: You will need to use the Blobblockservice. You can refer to this question how to get that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56961005/python-upload-a-package-to-azure-using-sas-uriYou can refer to this question/answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50014827/write-python-dataframe-as-csv-into-azure-blob

Comment: I donot have account name or key, only thing i have is blob sas url. 
I wish not download to a local machine and upload to storage container

Comment: See my modified answer above. If this answers your question, kindly mark it as the answer.