# python write a dataframe as csv to azure storage account

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-data-lake

I am able to read a csv file from Azure storage container as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68839684/python-read-from-azure-storage-account).

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

sas_url = "<your_blob_sas url>"
blob_client = BlobClient.from_blob_url(sas_url)
blob_data = blob_client.download_blob()
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(blob_data.content_as_text()))
print(df)
```

Can someone help with a python code that writes the data to a storage container?

I have container setup, with BLOB SAS URL

I don't have account name, key or any other information, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50014827/write-python-dataframe-as-csv-into-azure-blob)

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [BlobClient API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python#upload-blob-data--blob-type--blobtype-blockblob---blockblob----length-none--metadata-none----kwargs-). Since you already know how to instantiate the client it's just:

```
blob_client.upload_blob(df.to_csv(index=False))
```

Comment: I get ResesourceExistsError with below code,

sas_url = "https....."

blob_client = BlobClient.from_blob_url(sas_url)

blob_data = blob_client.upload_blob(region.to_csv(index=False))

Comment: Visit API docs again and add `overwrite=True`. And note other useful options like encoding, timeout... tune it to your needs.